# How can I read and write CSV in a way similar to NET FileHelpers?

Tags: delphi, csv, import, export

Anyone know how I can import/export csv, txt files in a way similar to NET FileHelpers, but using Delphi, taking spaces and quotes into account and handling traditional CSV escaping rules in a manner similar to the way CSV escaping works in Excel?

ref. link http://www.filehelpers.com/

If your answer tends to be: "why this lazy guy dont write a simple CSV parser", consider this 5 minutes reading and then you will know why CSV parsing is not trivial:

http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp

Comment: Actually the task is split into two: first write a tokenizer that will count for quotes and spaces (throw away regexes, most of the time you can live easier without them), then use the tokenizer to parse the CSV line by line. Writing a correct and complete tokenizer took me an hour or so.

Comment: and exporting is even easier. I wrote my own exporter recently with a goal of high performance.

Comment: why you linked page ranting about those obvious things? actually looking into the problem takes less time than seeking random advice in teh internets.

Comment: exporting is definitely easier than parsing. To anybody who thinks CSV parsing is trivial; Send me your CSV parser, and I'll show you ten real-world CSV input files that will break your parser.

Comment: @Eugene: im probably missing something here but why the need to count spaces?

Comment: @Simon mistake in wording. Let's say "take spaces and quotes into account".

Comment: I changed the text of this question so it fits the new rule that you can not ask about what library to use, only HOW to do a task.

Comment: Wow, see, the close police are here in seconds.

Comment: @WarrenP we like to keep Stack Overflow clean and free of spam. Recommendation questions attract spam.

Comment: As I said I'm fixing it, so can you lay off Jan?

Comment: You may want to see this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/783493/Delphi-CSV-File-and-String-Reader-Classes . It is just one single PAS file. Easy to use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wrote a Dataset (TTable-like object) for Jedi project called TJvCsvDataSet that follows all CSV parsing rules in a way similar to the CSV parsing rules used by Excel and various database and report tools that import and export CSVs.

You can install JVCL, drop a TJvCsvDataSet on your form.

It also contains a stream class that will very quickly load a file on disk, and parse it line by line, using the correct escape rules required for CSV files, even files that include carriage-return/line-feed codes encoded within a field.

You just drop it on your form, and set the FieldDefs property like this:

CsvFieldDef=ABC:%,DEF:#,GHI:$,....

There are special codes for integer, floating point, iso date-time, and other fields. It even allows you to map a wide-string field to a utf8 field in a CSV file.

There is a designtime property editor to save you from having to declare the CSV Field Defs using the syntax above, instead you can just pick visually what the column types are.

If you don't set up a CSV Field Def, it merely maps whatever exists in the file to string-type fields.

Jedi JVCL:
http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/

JvCsvDataSet Docs:

http://help.delphi-jedi.org/unit.php?Id=3107

http://help.delphi-jedi.org/item.php?Id=174896

[image]

Comment: P, is it capable or easy to implement a "N lines" layout. i mean first line has one layout, second another, like a master detail?

Comment: The component is tolerant of missing fields and values.  That is as far as it goes.  You can have a CSV database, and you can keep adding fields to it, and it will load a file that was created before that field was added.  It doesn't even care if you reorder the fields.  It is pretty darn smart. But it's not magic, and it won't have completely different sets of data on each line, no.

Comment: If you wanted to implement a different layout on each line, you would not want a TTable component. But perhaps you might find it easy to start by grabbing my stream class, and my CSV-splitter class, and then wrap those into whatever it is that you wanted to do, that isn't csv exactly, but is delimited text.

Comment: Nice component Warren. Certainly very fast and reliable. Just curious - how to optimize the memory usage? Just by defining the fields? Or is there an optimum value (way to calculate) for TextStreamBuffer? (D7)

Comment: @WarrenP I tried to use this component but it choked on fields containing double quotes (reported it with a test case). In any case, it looks quite nice.

Comment: Leonardo: You should post some sample data and log a bug at the Jedi Bug Tracker. I would definitely fix such a bug as quick as I am able to. Need more data.

Comment: It gives me out of memory errors, even with a fairly small file of only a couple of MB's.

Comment: So did you post a bug on the Jedi Bug Tracker? What good does a comment here do? Do you have lines that are longer than 4K for a single line? If so, this is a known limitation, and the workaround is also well known.

Comment: Ironically, the gods of StackOverflow have decided that this kind of thing is not a good type of question here. (Suggest a library? Instant close.) And yet this question has 6K views and has helped many people!)

Comment: This component looks great. I would love use it. But it has an internal (hardcoded?) limit of 120 columns/fields. I have a table with 210 fields, and so the library gripes at runtime when I activate the data set. Any suggestions on getting around this?

Comment: FYI: For the hardcoded 120 field limit, I simply bumped up`JvCsv_MAXCOLUMNS` in `jvcl/run/JvCsvData.pas`. And then before opening the table at runtime, I read my field defs and adjust `JvCsvDataSet.TextBufferSize` to some obnoxious width to account for my line lengths. Now the control is working great, thanks for this component @WarrenP

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty basic, but `TStringList` has `Delimiter`, `DelimitedText`, and `QuoteChar` properties, which address some of these  issues.

Updated to add, per comments: Don't be tempted by the `CommaText` property, which has some surprising limitations for backwards compatibility with archaic versions of Delphi.

Comment: @David, it does address all of the specific points in the blog post. It is not, as I stated, comprehensive, but if you have insights as to the details of José's needs, feel free to share them.

Comment: Craig, does TStringList solves all of the many mini quirks CSV has? (strings inside quotes, newlines inside quotes, missing values, etc.)

Comment: @Craig I'm sorry, but you won't get far with TStringList. A space is always considered a delimiter!! Plus you'd need one string list per row, even if it could parse it.

Comment: @David, that's just wrong. The "space" issue is true for `CommaText`, but not for `DelimitedText`. Which is why I didn't suggest it, even for CSV. @Leandro, some, but not all. Whether it's suitable depends on your needs, but it has the particular advantage of being built in.

Comment: @Craig I'm reading the help file which states: "When assigning DelimitedText, the value is parsed as SDF formatted text. For SDF format, strings are separated by Delimiter characters or **spaces**", my emphasis. But later on it states "If StrictDelimiter is set to false, the space character is also interpreted as a delimiter, regardless of the value of Delimiter. This is not true when the space character occurs between quotation marks." This StrictDelimiter property has not always been present which may explain my misunderstanding and consequent erroneous comments.

Comment: @Craig I fixed a typo in your answer and thus also gave me an opportunity to remove my down-vote.

Comment: @Craig Actually I'm not sure that StrictDelimiter is relevant at all. I think I've just been seduced by CommaText in the past and my disappointment with it has coloured my opinions of TStringList's ability to do this. Please accept my apologies. Downvote converted to upvote!

Comment: @David it is certainly true that `CommaText` and `DelimitedText` have (surprisingly) different rules and I should probably note that in my answer.

Comment: @Craig Did my upvote tip you over the magic 50k barrier?!! Nice work! Currently at a cool round 50000!

Comment: Trying to use TStringList to parse non-trivial real-world CSV files will end up an exercise in frustration. Use a dedicated class like the one Misha posts about below, or the one I wrote (JVCL JvCsvDataSet).  TStringList can not handle embedded cr-lf esaped within a csv file, and so it's not safe to recommend for real world use.

Comment: I'm looking at an 'archaic' version of Delphi, but the problem with stringlist is that LoadFromFile / LoadFromStream parse "into strings separated by carriage return or linefeed characters". From there, it doesn't matter if you use CommaText which uses DelimitedText: they don't notice LF or CR or space characters unless you specify one of those characters as the delimiter.        (But I use a full-feature or custom csv unit if I want compatibility with some other csv: if you want compatiblity there is always something you have to fiddle)

Answer (score 3):

My framework has code for this in the CsiTextStreamsUnt.pas file (see http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_delphi.htm)

Comment: Does it handle carriage-return linefeeds embedded inside a csv row?

Comment: I intentionally removed this functionality about a year ago because there is no standard way to handle records across multiple lines for both file reading and writing. Instead I introduced an overridable method:

Comment: Trying again: I intentionally removed this functionality about a year ago because there is no standard way to handle records spanning multiple lines for both reading and writing (and really there is no point tryng). Instead I introduced two overrideable methods, one for reading, one for writing, that enable a developer to add any type of multi-line record handling that they require.

Comment: Agree, Misha, there's no one standard way, but there is one most common way that it is seen.  That is what I call the "defacto" rule.  Whatever Excel does.   So, maybe you could enable 'excel flag'.

Comment: Good point, although given that I have never had to use this in any real-world scenarios I put it under the YAGNI principle, and if I do need it, I will override my methods. I have at least 20,000 LOC in just implementing utility routines and classes that I have actually used in live applications over the last 10 years - it would be way too much effort to add things that I might not need ;-)

Comment: @Misha-I would like to try it but the link is not working

Answer (score 3):

Here some code I wrote that reads CSV files, it handles carriage returns inside quotes as well.

```
unit CSV;

interface
uses
  SysUtils, Generics.Collections, IOUtils;

type
  TParseState = (psRowStart, psFieldStart, psUnquotedFieldData,
    psQuotedFieldData, psQFBranch, psEndOfQuotedField, psQFEndSearch,
    psEndOfLine, psEndOfFile);

  TCSVField = class
  strict private
    FText: String;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Text: string read FText write FText;
    procedure Clear;
  end;

  TCSVFieldList = class(TObjectList<TCSVField>)
  public
    function AddField(const AText: string): TCSVField;
    procedure ClearFields;
  end;

  TCSVRow = class
  strict private
    FFields: TCSVFieldList;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Fields: TCSVFieldList read FFields;
  end;

  TCSVParser = class
  strict private
    FRow: TCSVRow;
    FContent: String;
    FCIdx: Integer;
    FParseState: TParseState;
    FEOF: Boolean;
    procedure ParseRow;
  public
    function First: Boolean;
    function EOF: Boolean;
    function Next: Boolean;
    procedure OpenFile(AFileName: String);
    procedure OpenText(const AText: string);
    property Row: TCSVRow read FRow;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation



{implementation of TCSVField}

procedure TCSVField.Clear;
begin
  FText:= '';
end;

constructor TCSVField.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
end;

destructor TCSVField.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

{implementation of TCSVRow}

constructor TCSVRow.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FFields:= TCSVFieldList.Create;
end;

destructor TCSVRow.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FFields);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

{implementation of TCSVParser}

constructor TCSVParser.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FRow:= TCSVRow.Create;
  FCIdx:= 1;
  FParseState:= psEndOfFile;
end;

destructor TCSVParser.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FRow);
  inherited Destroy;
end;



function TCSVParser.EOF: Boolean;
begin
  Result:= FEOF;
end;

function TCSVParser.First: Boolean;
begin
  FEOF:= False;
  FCIdx:= 1;
  FParseState:= psRowStart;
  Result:= Next;
end;

function TCSVParser.Next: Boolean;
begin
  if not EOF then
    ParseRow;
  Result:= not EOF;
end;

procedure TCSVParser.OpenFile(AFileName: String);
begin
  OpenText(TFile.ReadAllText(AFileName));
end;

procedure TCSVParser.OpenText(const AText: string);
begin
  FContent:= AText;
  FRow.Fields.Clear;
  First;
end;

procedure TCSVParser.ParseRow;
var
  FieldIdx: Integer;

  procedure AddField(const AText: string);
  begin
    if FieldIdx > FRow.Fields.Count-1 then
      FRow.Fields.AddField(AText)
    else
      FRow.Fields[FieldIdx].Text:= AText;

    Inc(FieldIdx);
  end;

var
  FieldText: string;
  Curr: Char;
  LastIdx: Integer;
begin
  if FParseState = psEndOfFile then
  begin
    FEOF:= True;
    FRow.Fields.ClearFields;
    Exit;
  end;

  if not (FParseState in [psRowStart]) then
    raise Exception.Create('ParseRow requires ParseState = psRowState');

  FieldIdx:= 0;
  FRow.Fields.ClearFields;
  LastIdx:= Length(FContent);
  while True do
  begin
    case FParseState of
      psRowStart:
        begin
          if FCIdx > LastIdx then
          begin
            FEOF:= True;
            FParseState:= psEndOfFile;
          end
          else
          begin
            FParseState:= psFieldStart;
          end;
          Dec(FCIdx); // do not consume
        end;
      psFieldStart:
        begin
          FieldText:= '';
          if FContent[FCIdx] = '"' then
            FParseState:= psQuotedFieldData
          else
          begin
            FParseState:= psUnquotedFieldData;
            Dec(FCIdx); // do not consume
          end;
        end;
      psUnquotedFieldData:
        begin
          if FCIdx > LastIdx then
          begin
            AddField(FieldText);
            FParseState:= psEndOfFile;
          end
          else
          begin
            Curr:= FContent[FCIdx];
            case Curr of
              #13, #10:
                begin
                  AddField(FieldText);
                  FParseState:= psEndOfLine;
                end;
              ',':
                begin
                  AddField(FieldText);
                  FParseState:= psFieldStart;
                end;
            else
              FieldText:= FieldText + Curr;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      psQuotedFieldData:
        begin
          if FCIdx > LastIdx then
            raise Exception.Create('EOF in quoted Field.');

          Curr:= FContent[FCIdx];
          if Curr = '"' then
            FParseState:= psQFBranch
          else
            FieldText:= FieldText + Curr;
        end;
      psQFBranch:
        begin
          Curr:= FContent[FCIdx];
          if Curr = '"' then
          begin
            FieldText:= FieldText + Curr;
            FParseState:= psQuotedFieldData;
          end
          else
          begin
            AddField(FieldText);
            FParseState:= psEndOfQuotedField;
            Dec(FCIdx); // do not consume
          end;
        end;
      psEndOfQuotedField:
        begin
          if FCIdx > LastIdx then
            FParseState:= psEndOfFile
          else
          begin
            Curr:= FContent[FCIdx];
            if CharInSet(Curr, [#13, #10]) then
              FParseState:= psEndOfLine
            else
            begin
              FParseState:= psQFEndSearch;
              Dec(FCIdx); // do not consume
            end;
          end;
        end;
      psQFEndSearch:
        begin
          if FCIdx > LastIdx then
            FParseState:= psEndOfFile
          else
          begin
            Curr:= FContent[FCIdx];
            if CharInSet(Curr, [#13, #10]) then
              FParseState:= psEndOfLine
            else if Curr = ',' then
              FParseState:= psFieldStart;

            // skips white space or other until end
          end;
        end;
      psEndOfLine:
        begin
          if FCIdx > LastIdx then
            FParseState:= psEndOfFile
          else
          begin
            Curr:= FContent[FCIdx];
            if not CharInSet(Curr, [#13, #10]) then
            begin
              FParseState:= psRowStart;
              Break; // exit loop, we are done with this row
            end;
          end;
        end;
      psEndOfFile:
        begin
          Break;
        end;
    end;
    Inc(FCIdx);
  end;
end;


{ TCSVFieldList }

function TCSVFieldList.AddField(const AText: string): TCSVField;
begin
  Result:= TCSVField.Create;
  Add(Result);
  Result.Text:= AText;
end;

procedure TCSVFieldList.ClearFields;
var
  F: TCSVField;
begin
  for F in Self do
    F.Clear;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the VCL TXMLTransform logic, I wrote a TCsvTransform class helper that translates a .csv format structure to /from a TClientDataSet.
For more details about TCsvTransform, cf http://didier.cabale.free.fr/delphi.htm#uCsvTransform.
NB: I set the same field type symbols as Warren's TJvCsvDataSet

Answer (score 0):

My functions

```
function ParseCSVString(s: string; const delimiter: Char = ','; const enclosure: Char = '"'): TStrings;
var
    i,len: Integer;
    f: string;
    inQuoted: Boolean;
begin
    Result := TStringList.Create;
    len := Length(s);
    if len = 0 then Exit;
    //Test,Test;"Test;Test";"Test""Test";;
    f := '';
    inQuoted := False;
    i:=0;
    while i < len do
    begin
        Inc(i);
        if s[i] = enclosure then
        begin
            if inQuoted and (i<len) and (s[i+1] = enclosure) then
            begin
                f := f + '"';
                i:=i+1;
            end
            else
                inQuoted := not inQuoted;
        end
        else if s[i] = delimiter then
        begin
            if inQuoted then
                f := f+s[i]
            else
            begin
                Result.Add(f);
                inQuoted := false;
                f := '';
            end;
        end
        else
            f := f + s[i];
    end;
    Result.Add(f);
end;

function EscapeCSVString(s: string; const delimiter: Char = ','; const enclosure: Char = '"'): string;
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := StringReplace(s,enclosure,enclosure+enclosure,[rfReplaceAll]);
    if (Pos(delimiter,s) > 0) OR (Pos(enclosure,s) > 0) then
        Result := enclosure+Result+enclosure;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this [Delphi CSV File and String Reader Classes for Delphi 2009 and later](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/783493/Delphi-CSV-File-and-String-Reader-Classes) today on CodeProject, I've not tried it, but from the example code it's kinda cool. Written by Vladimir Nikitenko, the main class is TnvvCSVReader.