# Stringlist and CSV

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How can i access the individual records based on Index in Stringlist after loading this CSV file in to it.

CSV Example:

```
   Record0;Record1;Record2
   Record0;Record1;Record2
   Record0;Record1;Record2
   Record0;Record1;Record2
```

Comment: After reading a line into `line`, `line[i]` (or `line.Strings[i]`) will get the i:th record (see http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854310/anyone-knows-a-free-delphi-32-library-to-import-export-csv-files-like-net-fileh

Comment: IMHO easiest is to use [`SplitString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString) function.

Comment: Post as answers. So i can accept. whatever comes close.

Comment: @TLama Except that breaks down when your strings contain commas and are escaped inside quotes.

Comment: @Joey None of these are answers.

Comment: I updated the question. @DavidHeffernan well potential are.

Comment: @David, not for the example OP posted...

Comment: @TLama Well, you don't need to write a computer program if you restrict yourself to operating on a single set of input data. Just consider what happens if the program attempts to operate on different data.

Comment: CSV Files are well defined by RFC4180 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Comment: FWIW, what your question asks for is actually impossible. `List[0]` is a string and strings don't have methods. Also, why would you name the column `Line`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan doesn't really matter just how is the calling convention. As long you get individual strings out based on index.

Comment: @Sir - Your statement *"CSV Files are well defined"* is quite vaque. CSV have no standard and there are different implementations. Although RFC 4180 can be considered as an effort to have a standard, it is nothing more than a commonly used definition. In fact it (RFC 4180) states *"This memo provides information for the Internet community. It does not specify an Internet standard of any kind"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SplitString` will split your string with delimiters you define.
In this example space and ; character.

**Update**

Added an example of an indexed split function. (`SplitByIndex`).

**Update 2**

Added an example (`SplitByIndexAlt`) not using `SplitString`, but `TStringList.DelimitedText`.
This will treat spaces and ; as delimiter (not the ones enclosed by `QuoteChar`).

```
uses
  SysUtils,Classes,System.Types,System.StrUtils;

procedure Test(aStringList: TStringList);
var
  s,split : String;
  splittedString : TStringDynArray;
begin
  for s in aStringList do begin
    splittedString := SplitString(s,' ;'); // Splits at space and ;
    for split in splittedString do
    begin
      WriteLn(split);
    end;
  end;    
end;


Function SplitByIndex(aList : TStringList; aRow,aCol : Integer) : String;
// Zero based index !
var
  splittedString : TStringDynArray;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (aRow < aList.Count) then
  begin
    splittedString := SplitString(aList[aRow],' ;');
    if (aCol < Length(splittedString))
      then Result := splittedString[aCol];
  end;    
end;


Function SplitByIndexAlt(aList : TStringList; aRow,aCol : Integer) : String;
// Zero based index !
var
  splitlist : TstringList;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (aRow < aList.Count) then
  begin
    splitList := TStringList.Create;
    Try
      splitList.Delimiter := ';';
      // splitList.QuoteChar := '"'; // This may have to be changed
      splitList.StrictDelimiter := false;
      splitList.DelimitedText := aList[aRow];
      if (aCol < splitList.Count)
        then Result := splitList[aCol];
    Finally
      splitList.Free;
    End;
  end;
end;


var
  myList: TStringList;
begin
  myList := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    myList.Add('#0  Record0;Record1;Record2');
    myList.Add('#1  Record0;Record1;Record2');
    myList.Add('#2  Record0;Record1;Record2');
    myList.Add('#3  Record0;Record1;Record2');
    Test(myList);
    WriteLn(SplitByIndex(myList,0,4);
    ReadLn;
    Finally
      myList.Free;
    End;
end.
```

The output here will look like:

```
#0

Record0
Record1
Record2

etc
```

Now consider that a CSV file format is not standardised, see [CSV Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).
So for a more general solution the solution might look more complex.

Comment: This fails when one of the values contains a delimiter. In which case it would have been escaped by quoting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan &SirRufo, I know well the complexity of supporting CSV files. If a general solution was asked for there is none, since there is not an accepted standard for a CSV file.

Comment: @LURD I tested your solution with RandomRange(0,100000) it is insanly fast! :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, see my last addition. Delimiters enclosed by quoting is handled correct.

Comment: @Sir - A quick test (XE2) shows, 'SplitString' regards line feeds if they're enclosed in double quotes. Which item of the RFC does it violate?

Comment: @Sertac Does it remove the Quotes?

Comment: @Sertac the main problem is, that you have to add row by row to the StringList. But how do you know if the LineFeed in the File is a LineDelimiter or belongs to a Field. So you have to parse the File. After parsing a Stringlist can handle the real rows. But we are talking about a whole file and not for some rows out of a CSV

Comment: @Sir - That's correct. But I think it shouldn't translate to 'TStringList cannot be used for csv files'. And I'm not sure what are we talking about, the question is not very descriptive on that regard, or maybe you're correct, it mentions 'loading a file'. BTW, I believe these two comments belongs to your answer. ;)

Comment: @Sertac the test of that function here is wrong. with myList.Text := 'Record0;"Rec'#13#10'ord1";Record2'#13#10'Record0;Record1;Record2'#13#10; it will fail, but represent a content from a file

Comment: @Sir - What I said was, a stringlist confirms with the RFC if DelimitedText is assigned one record at a time. But I may have got lost at some point..

Answer (score 8):

You can't use a TStringList for CSV Files described in [RFC4180](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180&ei=ozGuUJbyO8XptQb37IDYDw&usg=AFQjCNEAoOXkSPh2XnTMXwniiQ4zh527iA&sig2=_xFtRUQ8NhEqQjvVn31b8A)

Example of a valid RFC4180 CSV File (2 Rows, 5 Fields)

```
Data1;"Data2;Data2";"Data3
Data3";"Data4""Data4""";Data5
Data1;"Data2;Data2";"Data3
Data3";"Data4""Data4""";Data5
```

and the single Field Values

1. Data1
2. Data2;Data2
3. Data3#13#10Data3
4. Data4"Data4"
5. Data5

but maybe you find this usable ([a quick sample i wrote in 2011](http://www.delphipraxis.net/1081747-post29.html)).

Do not get confused, that you can modify the Cell Value but no SaveToFile Method.

```
unit CSVData;

interface

type
  TCSVData = class
  private
    FData : array of array of string;
    FDelim : Char;
    FQuote : Char;
    function GetRows : Integer;
    function GetCols : Integer;
    function GetCell( Row, Col : Integer ) : string;
    procedure SetCell( Row, Col : Integer; const Value : string );
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure LoadFromFile( const FileName : string );
    property Cell[Row, Col : Integer] : string
      read GetCell
      write SetCell;
    property Rows : Integer
      read GetRows;
    property Cols : Integer
      read GetCols;
    property Delim : Char
      read FDelim
      write FDelim;
    property Quote : Char
      read FQuote
      write FQuote;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Classes;

{ TCSVData }

destructor TCSVData.Destroy;
begin
  SetLength( FData, 0, 0 );
  inherited;
end;

function TCSVData.GetCell( Row, Col : Integer ) : string;
begin
  Result := FData[Row, Col];
end;

function TCSVData.GetCols : Integer;
begin
  if Rows > 0
  then
    Result := Length( FData[0] )
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function TCSVData.GetRows : Integer;
begin
  Result := Length( FData );
end;

procedure TCSVData.LoadFromFile( const FileName : string );
var
  Data : TStrings;
  Val : string;
  MyChar : Char;
  LastChar : Char;
  QuotePart : Boolean;
  Col : Integer;
  Row : Integer;
  MaxCol : Integer;
begin
  Data := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Data.LoadFromFile( FileName );

    LastChar := #0;
    QuotePart := False;
    Val := '';
    MaxCol := 0;
    Col := 0;
    Row := 0;

    // Jedes Zeichen durchlaufen
    for MyChar in Data.Text do
      begin
        if ( MyChar = Quote )
        then
          begin
            // QuotePart wechselt den Status
            QuotePart := not QuotePart;

            // Befinden wir uns im QuotePart und das letzte Zeichen
            // war das Quote-Zeichen, dann handelt es sich um eine
            // Verdoppelung und wir hängen das Quote-Zeichen an
            // den Puffer
            if QuotePart and ( LastChar = Quote )
            then
              Val := Val + Quote;
          end
        else if not QuotePart and ( MyChar = Delim )
        then
          begin
            // Sind noch nicht genug Zeilen da ...
            if high( FData ) < Row + 1
            then
              // ... dann auf Verdacht schon mal 10 hinzufügen
              SetLength( FData, Row + 10 );
            // Sind noch nicht genug Spalten da ...
            if high( FData[Row] ) < Col + 1
            then
              // ... dann auf Verdacht schon mal 10 hinzufügen
              SetLength( FData[Row], Col + 10 );
            // Wert eintragen
            FData[Row, Col] := Val;
            // Puffer leeren
            Val := '';
            // Spalte hochzählen
            Inc( Col );
          end
        else if not QuotePart and ( ( MyChar = #13 ) or ( MyChar = #10 ) )
        then
          begin
            // Haben wir CR LF gefunden ...
            if ( MyChar = #10 ) and ( LastChar = #13 )
            then
              begin
                // Sind noch nicht genug Zeilen da ...
                if high( FData ) < Row + 1
                then
                  // ... dann auf Verdacht schon mal 10 hinzufügen
                  SetLength( FData, Row + 10 );
                // Die Anzahl der Spalten steht jetzt fest
                SetLength( FData[Row], Col + 1 );
                // MaxCol merken
                if Col > MaxCol
                then
                  MaxCol := Col;
                // Wert eintragen
                FData[Row, Col] := Val;
                // Puffer leeren
                Val := '';
                // Zeile hochzählen
                Inc( Row );
                // Neue Zeile => erste Spalte
                Col := 0;
              end;
          end
        else
          // Das aktuelle Zeichen an den Puffer hängen
          Val := Val + MyChar;
        // Das letzte Zeichen merken
        LastChar := MyChar;
      end;

    SetLength( FData, Row );

    // Das ist eigentlich nur notwendig, wenn die CSV-Datei falsch aufgebaut ist
    // und unterschiedliche Anzahl von Spalten in den Zeilen aufweist
    // Dieses ist allerdings nicht RFC-konform, aber wir wollen mal nicht so sein
    for Row := low( FData ) to high( FData ) do
      SetLength( FData[Row], MaxCol + 1 );

  finally
    Data.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TCSVData.SetCell( Row, Col : Integer; const Value : string );
begin
  FData[Row, Col] := Value;
end;

end.
```

PS: I know i have another approach using the State Pattern, but i can't find it ... maybe later

Comment: Why can't a TStringList be used for csv files?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz you did not cite the whole ;o) CSV Files described in RFC4180, Fields are allowed to contain LineFeeds

Comment: @Sir - What you probably mean is 'LoadFromFile' is not good for a csv file. Otherwise 'DelimitedText' have no problem with line feeds enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: @Sertac a StringList cannot handle a CSV file (as RFC4180). But it can handle complete rows out of a CSV file and will treat it as defined in RFC4180. But you have to get that complete rows by yourself. Why should i use a StringList? When i'm in position to hand over i'm already finished

Comment: @Sir - > *".. hand over .."* > That's quite fine, I was just challenging if a stringlist can or cannot be used with csv files. But in the context of the question (loading the file), which would seem I've missed, I think your assertion is fine too.

Comment: Excellent class Sir Rufo and works quite well, highly recommended. I've tested it on examples from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values and it handled quoted CRLF well, as well as quoted field with additional spaces like [delimiter][space][space]"field"[space][delimiter] and invalid CSV (different number of columns for each row). Neither MS Excel CSV import, TStringList or TMS software components couldn't parse these properly.