# Detect record/row separator in a CSV file

Tags: c++, delphi, csv

How can I programmatically detect what record/row separator is used in a CSV file. In 90% of the cases it is CR/LF pair, but sometimes it is either CR or LF.

It should also take into account that line feeds in quoted data fields can differ from the row/record separators.

How can I do that?

**Update:** I am only interested what is the row/record separator: CR/LF, CR, or LF.

Comment: If you show your existing code, we can answer a lot more specific.

Comment: Why is this tagged c++ and delphi at the same time?

Comment: I use C++Builder, so I can use either C++ or Pascal, if there is an already existing solution for it..

Comment: TStringList accepts all three alternatives for record/row separators. Line feeds in quoted data fields are more difficult. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13514388/576719) answer can handle that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open a file with iostreams in text mode, the library will take care about different line endings on either Linux, Windows or MacOS.

Line feeds in a quoted data field could be detected by counting unescaped quotes. If the number is odd, you might have an unterminated data field and hence a newline embedded.

When you want to know, which line separator is used, just read character wise until you get either CR or LF. If it's LF, you're done; if it's CR read the next character. If the next character is LF, your line ending is CR LF, otherwise it's just CR.

Comment: If it takes care of them automatically, how can I know which one are actualky used?

Comment: Thanks, Olaf. This seems the easiest way to do it!

Comment: Easiest would be using readymade CSV reading library or TJclStringList :-) Well, if you only need rows - then just TStringList :-)